# Clarification on orientjs

Tags: orientdb, orientjs

I have a few questions about this example from the orientjs github docs:

```
   var server = OrientDB({
     host: '10.0.1.5',
     port: 2424,
     username: 'root',
     password: 'root',
     servers : [{host : '10.0.1.5' , port : 2425}]
    });
```

1. I assume the servers array doesn't need to contain the server specified in host and port (i.e. 10.0.1.5:2424 in the example)? In other words, this one is included in the list?
2. The list of servers (including the one specified in host and port) are only used on the initial connection, after which the list of servers in the cluster are automatically maintained as they come and go?
3. How is the target server selected (first available, round-robin, randomly, load balanced, etc.)?
4. Is the server only selected per-connect (as opposed to per-query/transaction)?
5. What happens if the selected server fails? Is a new connection attempted to a different server transparently or is some exception generated that requires the calling code to participate in selecting a new server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) yes does not need to contain the server.

2) yes they are used for the first connection then,  when connected each time the cluster shape changes the driver gets notified.

3) The connection is established with the first in the list. then it will stick there until fails.

4) per-connect

5) transparently retry the next server in the list

Comment: Thanks for the concise answers. But it concerns me that all clients (assuming they have the same configuration) will essentially connect to the same server (assuming it's live). While I could random-sort the list to get a crude form of load-distribution, what are the recommended way(s) to balance the load? Also, I seem to recall something about the 2.2 version of orientjs having some additional support for load balancing. Short of that, I'm running on AWS--what about using an Elastic Load Balancer and having the clients connect to that one IP?

Comment: No Eric for now there is no load balancing on driver side. 
It should be implemented in java driver side. But it could be easily implemented on orientjs as well. At least the round robin stuff.
I've raise an issue about that
https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientjs/issues/173